# why no location staff in golang time.Equal?

Tags: go

at http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/time.go

```
62  // Equal reports whether t and u represent the same time instant.
63  // Two times can be equal even if they are in different locations.
64  // For example, 6:00 +0200 CEST and 4:00 UTC are Equal.
65  // This comparison is different from using t == u, which also compares
66  // the locations.
67  func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool {
68      return t.sec == u.sec && t.nsec == u.nsec
69  }
```

why they do not care t.loc and u.loc?

update:
If I had 2 servers(different location)and how can I judge if their time is equal exactly？

Comment: The answer is right in the above Go source code comment.

Answer (score 10):

a `Time` stores an **UTC** timestamp. Which means it isn't dependant of the location.

The times `6:00 +0200 CEST` and `4:00 UTC` have the same value UTC. They are the exact same moment in time.

The location is used only for localized representation of this time.

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/time.go?s=1541:2055#L24) :

> Changing the location in this way changes only the presentation; it does not change the instant in time

Comment: I didn't see your answer (published 1 minute before mine). +1 to you, sir.

Answer (score 4):

- `t.sec` gives the the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, year 1 00:00:00 UTC.
- `n.nsec` specifies a non-negative nanosecond offset within the second named by Seconds. (range [0, 999999999])

That [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) doesn't depend on location.